# Javascript: Setting parameters to functions that are being passed as a paramater

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance

I have a class errorHander which has the following function defined:

```
function handleError(errorData, callback, message) {
```

I can now pass the handleError function as a parameter into functions that can take a function to handle the error message. eg:

```
var signboards = devicesService.query()
        .$promise.then(function success(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $scope.devices = data;
        }, errorHandler.handleError);
```

The callback function is run and has the first variable (errorData) set to whatever error information is returned from the server. The success function is written out in full to display the way parameters are passed.

The problem is, that I would like to set the additional parameters as defined in my original handleError function. I would like to set the callback and message parameters.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: will that callback function and message be defined in your controller?

Comment: I was hoping to have the callback function and the message be dynamic as possible.. so adding it inline would be great. The possibility of nesting 'errorHandle.handleError' functions inside themselves would be great. The errorHandle is a singleton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a demo in pure js but should be easy to port:

http://plnkr.co/edit/4xB5JkXPvxK4mhCW66ik?p=preview

You can do a partial-like thing with the function:

```
$scope.errorCallback = function(errorData, callback, message) { ... }
$scope.errorCallbackPartial = function(callback, message) {
   return function(errorData) {
       errorCallback(errorData, callback, message)
   }
}
```

So in your example errorHandler.handleError with errorHandler.errorCallbackPartial(someCallback, someMessage), where the callback and message are written by you. Then it will work as expected.

Comment: Yes, I figured I could go this route. I suppose I was wondering if it was possible to bind additional variables which can be additional parameters to the function being called.